# Копирование из таблицы в таблицу по условию существования идентификатора

Tags: mysql

Как скопировать значения всех `id` из таблицы `post` в поле `news_id` таблицы `post_ex`, которые больше максимального `news_id` таблицы `post_ex`. Т.е. скопировать без дублей.

Так проходит просто копирование:

```
insert into `post_ex` (`news_id`) select `post`.`id` from `post`
```

Как ввести условие, чтобы копировались только те значения, которых ещё нет?

Comment: Условия "которые больше максимального news_id таблицы post_ex" и "Скопировать без дублей" совсем не одинаковы. Опишите еще раз задачу.

Comment: Без дублей. Но уже помогли на другом ресурсе. Решение:
insert into `post_ex` (`news_id`) select `post`.`id` from `post` where not exists (select 1 from post_ex where news_id=post.id)

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев:*

```
INSERT INTO
  post_ex (news_id)
SELECT
  post.id
FROM
  post
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM post_ex
              WHERE news_id = post.id)
```